# Activar botón solo si se cumple las condiciones

Tags: javascript, html

La idea que el el botón de calcular se active solo si se cumplen las condiciones de las variables de alturas 1 se encuentre entre 30 metros y 200 metros , altura 2 se encuentre entre 1 metro y 10 metros, de igual forma para la frecuencia entre 150 y 1500. Si la condición no se cumple debe generarse un alerta que indique al usuario el cambio de valor que se requiera.
El problema se presenta pues aunque los valores iniciales están correctos, el botón inicia desactivado, he intentado hacer otros cambios, pero no resuelven el problema.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>ttt</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cell-md-4">
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header clear">Altura1</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="htx" value="35" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Altura" placeholder="Ingrese la altura" onchange="updatehtx();">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header clear">Altura2</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="hrx" value="1.5" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Altura" placeholder="Ingrese la altura" onchange="updatehrx();">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Frecuencia</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="frecuencia" value="150" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Frecuencia [MHz]" placeholder="Ingrese la frecuencia" onchange="updatefreq();">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
 <div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Seleccione Entorno</div>
<div class="card-content p-4">
<form>
<select name="Entorno" id="Entorno">
<option disabled selected>Elija una opci&oacute;n</option>
<option value="ciudades">Cuidades pequeñas y medianas</option>
<option value="metropolitana">&Aacute;rea metropolitana</option>
<option value="suburbano">Ambiente suburbano</option>
<option value="rural">&Aacute;rea rural</option>
</select> 
</form>
<button id="calcular">Calcular</button> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>                  
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Resultado</div>
 <div class="card-content p-3">
  <input id="r" type="text" data-role="input" data-prepend="Resultado : " data-append="dB" disabled>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>                     
 </div>
 </div>
<script>

             var calcular = document.getElementById("calcular");
             calcular.disabled = true;          


            function updatehrx(hr){
                var hr = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hrx").value);
                if(hr => 1 && hr <= 10){
                calcular.disabled = true;
                calcular.classList.remove("disabled");
                
                }else{calcular.disabled = false;
                      alert("Modelo no valido para la altura " + hr + "m. ");               
                }
                }            
             
                         
            function updatehtx(ht){
               var ht = parseFloat(document.getElementById("htx").value);
               if(ht => 30 && ht <= 200){
                calcular.disabled = true;
                calcular.classList.remove("disabled");             
               }else{calcular.disabled = false;
                     alert("Modelo no valido para la altura " + ht + "m. ");                
                }
                }               
 
            function updatefreq(freq){
               var freq = parseFloat(document.getElementById("frecuencia").value);
               if(freq => 150 && freq <=1500){
                calcular.disabled = true;
                calcular.classList.remove("disabled");
               }else{   calcular.disabled = false;
                        alert("Modelo no valido para la altura " + freq + "MHz. ");             
                }
                }           
            
           document.querySelector('#calcular').addEventListener('click', () =>{
            const op = document.querySelector('#Entorno').value;
              let resultado;
              var frequency = parseFloat(document.getElementById("frecuencia").value);
              var hrx = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hrx").value);
              var htx = parseFloat(document.getElementById("htx").value);
            
            //Seleccion de entorno
            
            
            if (op == "ciudades") {
            resultado = 1; }
            
            else if (op == "metropolitana") {
    
               resultado=2;}

            else if (op == "suburbano") {
     
                 resultado = 3;
                 
                   }
 
            else if (op == "rural") {   
                 resultado=4;
                 
                  }      

            
             document.getElementById('r').value = resultado;
                  
  
                  });
    
   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var calcular = document.getElementById("calcular");
  calcular.disabled = true;
  //creamos variables globales booleanas
  var alt1 = false;
  var alt2 = false;
  var fre  = false;
  //tu consulta estaba mal porque => esto no significa mayor o igual, mayor o igual se escribe de la siguiente manera ">=" pero si usas mayor o igual tienes que tomar en cuenta por ejemplo que si la frecuencia es 150 entonces genera error.
  $("#htx").change(function(){
  var ht = parseFloat(document.getElementById("htx").value);
      //si la validacion falla, queda alt1 en caso contrario alt1 true
    if(ht < 30 || ht > 200){
        $("#htx").focus();
        alt1 = false;
        calcular.disabled = true;
        alert("Modelo no valido para la altura " + ht + "m. ");
     }else{
          alt1 = true;
     } 
     //con estas variables hacemos validaciones
     //si alt2 es false y fre es false entonces no habilitamos el boton en caso contrario que todos sean true habilitamos el boton y esta misma validacion la tenemos que repetir en cada uno de los input-
     if(alt2 == false || fre == false){
        calcular.disabled = true;
     }else if(alt1 == true && fre == true && alt2 == true){
          calcular.disabled = false;
      }
    })
  $("#hrx").change(function(){
    var hr = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hrx").value);
    
    if(hr < 1 || hr > 10){
        $("#hrx").focus();
        alt2 = false;
        calcular.disabled = true;
        alert("Modelo no valido para la altura " + hr + "m. ");
      }else{
          alt2 = true;
      } 
      
      if(alt1 == false || fre == false){
        calcular.disabled = true;
      }else if(alt1 == true && fre == true && alt2 == true){
          calcular.disabled = false;
      }
  });
     $("#frecuencia").change(function(){
     var freq = parseFloat(document.getElementById("frecuencia").value);
    if(freq < 150 || freq > 1500){
        $("#hrx").focus();
        alert("Modelo no valido para la altura " + freq + "MHz. ");
        calcular.disabled = true;
        fre = false;
     }else{
        fre = true;
     } 
     
     if(alt1 == false || alt2 == false){
        calcular.disabled = true;
     }else if(alt1 == true && fre == true && alt2 == true){
          calcular.disabled = false;
      }
  });      
      
  document.querySelector('#calcular').addEventListener('click', () =>{

    const op = document.querySelector('#Entorno').value;
    let resultado;
    //en el select colocamos el value por defecto en -1 y hacemos       una validacion
            
    //Seleccion de entorno
    if(op == -1){
      alert("debes seleccionar el entorno")
    }else{
      
        if (op == "ciudades") {
          resultado = 1;
        }else if(op == "metropolitana"){
          resultado=2;
        }else if (op == "suburbano") {
            resultado = 3;
        }else if (op == "rural") {   
            resultado=4;
        }
        document.getElementById('r').value = resultado;
      }

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>ttt</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cell-md-4">
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header clear">Altura1</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="htx"  type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Altura" placeholder="Ingrese la altura">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header clear">Altura2</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="hrx" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Altura" placeholder="Ingrese la altura">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Frecuencia</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="frecuencia" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Frecuencia [MHz]" placeholder="Ingrese la frecuencia">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
 <div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Seleccione Entorno</div>
<div class="card-content p-4">
<form>
<select name="Entorno" id="Entorno">
<option disabled selected value="-1">Elija una opci&oacute;n</option>
<option value="ciudades">Cuidades pequeñas y medianas</option>
<option value="metropolitana">&Aacute;rea metropolitana</option>
<option value="suburbano">Ambiente suburbano</option>
<option value="rural">&Aacute;rea rural</option>
</select> 
</form>
<button id="calcular">Calcular</button> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>                  
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Resultado</div>
 <div class="card-content p-3">
  <input id="r" type="text" data-role="input" data-prepend="Resultado : " data-append="dB" disabled>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>                     
 </div>
 </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Hola, ya edite el codigo para que lo revises,  De igual manera te dejo con comentarios la explicacion del codigo.
Saludos

Comment: Hola, me gustaría deshabilitar el botón para que no entregue ningún resultado hasta que los datos estén correctos, porque como puedes ver, la alerta se genera pero entrega un resultado, con un dato erróneo.

Comment: hola, ya hice la modificacion en el codigo como lo quieres. Si ejecutas el codigo veras que funciona bien. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la solución!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con simples *if* y *else* pero también puedes hacerlo con funciones es mas legible y se entiende mejor por ejemplo:

30 metros y 200 metros.

Puedes hacer una función que tome como parámetro la altura como la siguiente:

```
isTheRightHeight= height => { return height >=30 && height <= 200 ? true: false}
isTheRightHeight= height => { return height >=30 && height <= 200} <-- mas corto
```

Pero me gusta mas la primera opción le entiendo mejor:

```
const firstHeight = isTheRightHeight(30)
const secondHeight = 'otra funcion' <--
const frecuencie = 'otra funcion '
```

Y así para las demás condiciones ya después evalúas dentro un *if* tus condiciones, por ejemplo:

```
(firstHeight &&secondHeight  && frecuencie )
? activas el botón 
: desactivas el botón
```

Así con cualquier cambio en las se activa o se desactiva el botón y puedes tomar esa funciones para activar el botón ya sea desde el inicio.